# Increment number every time button is click

Tags: c#, asp.net, increment

I want to increase an `int` variable `i` whenever I click on a button. But what I get is only `int` value of `1` and it doesn't increase anymore.

Here is my code:

```
private int i;

protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;

    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: did you define your variable i? Does it have initial value?

Comment: Winforms ? Or Web from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By each request (Clicking on the button), a new instance will be created.
So your non-static variable will be reset to `0`.

You can define `i` as static:

```
private static int i;
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;

    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

But please note that the `i` variable is shared between all the users.
To improve this issue, you can use `Session`.

`Session` is an ability to store data of each user in a session.

So you can use following property to change the `i` variable in each session:

```
private int i
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["i"] == null)
            return 0;

        return (int)Session["i"];

        // Instead of 3 lines in the above, you can use this one too as a short form.
        // return (int?) Session["i"] ?? 0;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["i"] = value;
    }
}

protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;

    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Will this not affect page_load?

Comment: I use Asp.net.I am going to save the label on my database later on.I was just curious if its going to have an effect on my page load.

Comment: @rainalasa, No, you only used this `i` variable in the `btnStart_Click` event.

Comment: Static will make the variable shared between all users of the web page. I'm not sure this is the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: If `user A` click the button after `user B` what will be the value of `i` for `lblStart.Text` in `user A's` window?

Comment: I see as long the webpage doens't reload.

Comment: @un-lucky yes something like that.I'm using this to track the number of **Orders** the customer purchase.So when he clicked the button it will count as **Order number 1** then when he purchased again it's        **order number 2**

Comment: Static variables have application scope in asp.net; So if any user increment the value will reflect for all others

Comment: @un-lucky, You're right, I updated the answer. To solve this problem `Session` will help us.

Answer (score 2):

As you know other answer is correct i want add another answer

You must in **webform** save your variables in `ViewState`

Just define your variables like this

```
public int i 
{
    get { Convert.ToInt32( ViewState["i"] ); }
    set { ViewState["i"] = value ; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert   lblStart.Text value to int every time and  assign it to i. Then increase i.

```
private int i;
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    i =   Int32.Parse(lblStart.Text);
    i++; 
    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar questions as yours and I believe the issue is because the event click did not store the value that has been increased before, therefore it could not be incremented the next time you clicked, so here's my code:

```
          protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
            string initial;
            int increment;
            int quantity;

            initial = TextBoxQty.Text; 
            increment = Convert.ToInt16(initial);
            increment++;
            TextBoxQty.Text = increment.ToString();
            quantity = increment;
            }
```

Comment: your approach is good, but keep in mind the single responsabity principle!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field, initialize them to 0.

```
private int i;
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    i =   int.Parse(myHiddenField.Value);
    i++; 
    myHiddenField.Value = i;
    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
protected static int a = 0;
    
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a = a+1;
    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

It Works for me but on page_load() it initiates the value from 1 again !

Answer (score -1):

this is actually my first time doing this

```
        int i = 0;

        while (i>=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Console.ReadLine();
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question was about a button tap and a function in an asp.net code.

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).